# SQL 4-valued logic table

Tags: sql, null, logic, grammar, database-agnostic

What are the truth tables for the proposed 4-value logic in SQL that has both an A-value null and an I-value null? From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#:%7E:text=Codd%20indicated%20in,still%20being%20published.).

Using `AND` for this, 3VL looks like this:

[image]

How would the following table look?

[image]

Comment: Also, in your first table it would be more adequate to refer to the three values as true, false, and **unknown** (as in T, F, U). Null is just a *boolean representation* of the unknown value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the representation of the UNKNOWN truth value as a null, with a real null stored in the database.

SQL defines three boolean values. Namely: True, False, and Unknown. The latter is represented by a null (but it's not a null).

Now, a bona fide SQL null represents a value that exists but that is just missing. For example: "we haven't got the birth date of Anne"; we know she has one, but we just don't have it on record yet. This corresponds to a Codd's A-value.

Codd's I-value corresponds to a value that cannot be later replaced by a real value, since this one doesn't actually exists. I-values are not currently represented in SQL.

Therefore, when you realize that nulls are only used in boolean logic to represent the Unknown value, then it's clear that they are unrelated to an A-value or an I-value; they live in separate **domains**. A 4-valued logic (with A an I values) doesn't make any sense since both of them don't really represent any boolean value.

Comment: I see thanks for this description. Do you have any recommendations of where I can learn more about the A-value and I-value approach?